# Combining 5 values in a WPARAM

Tags: mfc, bit-manipulation

I wrote this code years ago:

```
int CAssignSelectedColumnDlg::RegistryIntFromData(int iColumnIndex, int iCustomIndex, BOOL bAvoidConflicts, int iNumMeetings)
{
    WORD    wLowWord = MAKEWORD(iColumnIndex, iCustomIndex);
    WORD    wHighWord = MAKEWORD(bAvoidConflicts ? 1 : 0, iNumMeetings);

    return (int)MAKEWPARAM(wLowWord, wHighWord);
}
```

Now I revisit this code. I need to introduce a 5th number that is a `BOOL` 0/1. Is this possible?

Comment: The high byte of `wHighWord` seems to have 7 unused bits. Should be plenty to store a single bit of information.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. I saw this about flags: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/3-8a-bit-flags-and-bit-masks/ I am not sure how to combine two values into half a WORD. Also would there be any robust way to know if the int has 4 or 5 values? I ask this because existing users would have entries with 4 values which I will need to upgrade to 5. I don’t want to over complicate it. 

Comment: The only way to reliably tell the old and new encoding apart is by storing some sort of version indicator. A single bit in the upper 7 bits would do (e.g. bit 0: `bAvoidConflicts`, bit 1: `0` for old, `1` for new, bit 2: new data). Although this would really be a lot easier to read and write when using [bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field). Just let the compiler do the bit manipulation for you instead of doing it yourself, manually.

Comment: @IInspectable Interesting. I have not used bit fields before. If I changed to this bit field approach can the ultimate structure object be written as a single registry value though?

Comment: As long as the `struct` is no larger than a `WPARAM`, you can serialize it as a single `WPARAM` value. If you need to store this in the registry, there are probably better options. The registry supports writing binary data (`REG_BINARY`), allowing you to use any protocol. As an example, you could serialize your configuration data to a `CArchive`, backed by a memory stream, and write it out to the registry. The `CArchive` supports versionable schemas, making it possible to maintain compatibility.

Comment: @iinspectable In the end I just had a structure of bool and byte values and write it as binary data to registry. It is all working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `iColumnIndex`, `iCustomIndex`, and `iNumMeetings` cannot be more than `255`, it should be `BYTE`. You can add more `BOOL` values in `lobyte`, of `hiword`. The return value should be `unsigned int`. For backward compatibility you should probably leave the return value as `int`.

```
int foo(int iColumnIndex, int iCustomIndex,
    BOOL bAvoidConflicts, int iNumMeetings, BOOL bFifth)
{
    bAvoidConflicts = !!bAvoidConflicts;
    bFifth = !!bFifth;

    WORD loword = MAKEWORD(iColumnIndex, iCustomIndex);

    BYTE lobyte = (BYTE)(bAvoidConflicts << 0) | (BYTE)(bFifth << 1);
    BYTE hibyte = (BYTE)iNumMeetings;
    WORD hiword = MAKEWORD(lobyte, hibyte);

    return (int)MAKEWPARAM(loword, hiword);
}
```

And to check the values:

```
unsigned int res = foo(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5);

WORD loword = LOWORD(res);
WORD hiword = HIWORD(res);

BYTE iColumnIndex = LOBYTE(loword);
BYTE iCustomIndex = HIBYTE(loword);
BYTE lobyte       = LOBYTE(hiword);
BYTE iNumMeetings = HIBYTE(hiword);

BOOL bAvoidConflicts = !!(lobyte & 1);
BOOL bFifth = !!(lobyte & 2);

if(x1 != iColumnIndex) printf("error 1\n");
if(x2 != iCustomIndex) printf("error 2\n");
if(x3 != bAvoidConflicts) printf("error 3\n");
if(x4 != iNumMeetings) printf("error 4\n");
if(x5 != bFifth) printf("error 5\n");
```

Of course it would be easier if you just used a structure and store the values as `int`, `bool`, etc.

Here is a different version to add more bits, or to force a bit which indicates new version.

The names are confusing now. `bFifth` is the fifth parameter, and is the second bit `(bit1 << 1)`

`bit2` (the third bit!) is set to 1 for the new version

```
int foo(int iColumnIndex, int iCustomIndex,
    BOOL bAvoidConflicts, int iNumMeetings, BOOL bFifth)
{
    bAvoidConflicts = !!bAvoidConflicts;
    bFifth = !!bFifth;

    WORD loword = MAKEWORD(iColumnIndex, iCustomIndex);

    BOOL bit0 = bAvoidConflicts;
    BOOL bit1 = bFifth;
    BOOL bit2 = 1; //<-- always 1 to indicate new version

    BYTE lobyte = 0;
    lobyte |= (BYTE)(bit0 << 0);
    lobyte |= (BYTE)(bit1 << 1);
    lobyte |= (BYTE)(bit2 << 2);
    //lobyte |= (BYTE)(bit3 << 3);
    //lobyte |= (BYTE)(bit4 << 4);
    //lobyte |= (BYTE)(bit5 << 5);
    //lobyte |= (BYTE)(bit6 << 6);
    //lobyte |= (BYTE)(bit7 << 7);

    WORD hiword = MAKEWORD(lobyte, iNumMeetings);

    return (int)MAKEWPARAM(loword, hiword);
}
```

It can be checked the same way as before

```
int res = foo(255, 254, 1, 253, 1);

WORD loword = LOWORD(res);
WORD hiword = HIWORD(res);

BYTE iColumnIndex = LOBYTE(loword);
BYTE iCustomIndex = HIBYTE(loword);
BYTE iNumMeetings = HIBYTE(hiword);
BYTE lobyte       = LOBYTE(hiword);

BOOL b0 = !!(lobyte & 1);  //bAvoidConflicts
BOOL b1 = !!(lobyte & 2);  //bFifth
BOOL b2 = !!(lobyte & 4);  //version check
BOOL b3 = !!(lobyte & 8);  //not used
BOOL b4 = !!(lobyte & 16); //not used
BOOL b5 = !!(lobyte & 32); //not used
BOOL b6 = !!(lobyte & 64); //not used
BOOL b7 = !!(lobyte & 128);//not used
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason it isn’t a structure is that I had it in my head at the time to only write one registry key to hold all the information.

Comment: Are we able to extend this answer with the note provided to me in the comments to my question: “The only way to reliably tell the old and new encoding apart is by storing some sort of version indicator. A single bit in the upper 7 bits would do (e.g. bit 0: bAvoidConflicts, bit 1: 0 for old, 1 for new, bit 2: new data)”

Comment: *I had it in my head at the time to only write one registry key to hold all the information* I do these things too, it ends in regret. Anyway, see edit.